# CosmosDB sometimes doesn't return documents

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, robo3t, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I'm playing with CosmosDB as an alternative to MongoDB cluster but faced a strange issue.

I inserted several hundred documents into a collection. After that, I open Robo 3T tool (it's a tool for working with MongoDB) and try to query the top 50 documents, but it doesn't return anything. I even run `.count()` query and get 0 as a result. But after several tries, I can get these documents. When I restart Robo3T and do the same test, again several first requests don't return anything.

I have exactly the same issues when I read documents by C# application with MongoDB driver.

Did anybody face such issues? What I'm doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried querying from another tool to confirm whether the issue might be specific to Robo3T? It is possible that Cosmos is returning an unexpected response such as the collection exceeding the RU limit (i.e. a novel response that Cosmos would return but MongoDB does not).

Comment: I tried to query data programmatically (C# and Mongo driver) and sometimes get empty collection when I query all documents or even cannot get results when query documents by Id. As for exceeding the RU limits, I got these exceptions when uploaded documents to CosmosDb, so I suppose that when I get 0 results in C# app, it doesn't look like throttling issue. And I can get empty results when I do the first request in a day. But anyway I will increase limits to check your hypothesis.

Comment: Ha, I've tried to query the collection by Azure Data Explorer integrated into Azure Portal and even this tool doesn't return documents for several first requests :)